# Not able to bind static data using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

So, I load my page and I have my list items with their unique id's.

```
  <ul class="list-group" data-bind="template: { name: 'item-template', data: $root.items}">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span id="123" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Americanino</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
    </li>      

    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span id="223" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Asos</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
    </li>            
  </ul>
```

And I bind the attributes after page load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var itemListModel = function() {
    (...)
    self.item_id = ko.observable();
    (...)
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new itemListModel());
});
```

But when I try to remove a list item that is loaded from server

```
// Remove item
self.removeItem = function(item) {
    alert(self.item_id());
    //self.items.remove(item);
}
```

then I'm not able to retrieve the ID.

If I add a new item, then I can get the ID. But then I also get the same ID if I click any other list item as well.

So how can I bind "static" content?
Is it a problem that I have a hidden output that also has `data-bind="value: item_id"`?

[See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/JF55A/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your create_list method

```
function create_list(exiting_list){
var arr_list = [];

$(exiting_list).find('li').each(function(e,li){
    var id = $(li).find('span').prop('id');
    var name = $(li).find('span').html();
    arr_list.push(new item(id, name));
});
return arr_list;
```

}

Updated fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/JF55A/10/

Implemented the solution for sort .. updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/JF55A/11/

Comment: You don't even need to write `$parent.removeItem($data)` because the `$data` will be passed in automatically, so it would work the same with writing: `data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"` the point is on the `item.item_id`

Comment: Your solution is identical to Robert Rozas (with just more code). Se my last comment to his answer.

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is in your create_list method. arr_list.push({
            item_id: id,
            item_name: name
        });
Here the item_id is not treated as observable.

Comment: Eagle eye! Thanks for noticing that. I got it working now, thanks :)

Comment: @SherinMathew While you're at it, are you able to apply `self.sortItems = function() { self.items.sort(); };` as well? I've not been able to implement sorting. Followed the example here: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow if you have not found the solution. Its late here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54076/discussion-between-sherin-mathew-and-steven).